# keyboard layout switching doesn't work properly in gnome 3.

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3 installed from the regular repositories. I have two issues with the keyboard layout behavior (English and Hebrew):

1. When I switch the keyboard, the indicator on the screen actually show the opposite (Pointing on He when switch to En and vise averse)
2. The keyboard layout isn't separated between windows, even though this is I set it to behave.

Am I the only one who sees this? Is this a known bug?

I also have KDE installed on the machine, but I don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. Solved executing from command line the following After login:

```
$ setxkbmap -option "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll,compose:ralt" -layout es
```

(In this sample I set the layout to my natural language `es`)

I set this command as a default starting application when gnome starts.

Hope this helps.